# Identifier DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to use DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR package to write a CLOB columns to file. But it seems that the package does not exist in DB.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather say that you aren't granted to use it. Ask your DBA (or, if you have those privileges, do it yourself) to

```
grant execute on dbms_xslprocessor to your_user;
```

**[EDIT]**

The package exists in my 11g:

```
SQL> select object_name, object_type
  2  from dba_objects where object_name = 'DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR';

OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE
------------------------------ -------------------
DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR              SYNONYM
DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR              PACKAGE
DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR              PACKAGE BODY

SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

SQL>
```

What does your query return?

Comment: I am using SYS user, So rights wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Don't use SYS. Leave SYS and SYSTEM alone, they are *special*, they own the database, they are powerful. If you accidentally do something wrong, you might destroy the database. Do (whatever you're doing) in another schema. Apart from that: that package *exists* at least since 10g (while you're on 11g) so I doubt that it isn't there. Could you post code you wrote?

Comment: I understand that, But this is a test database. I need not worry if anything goes wrong either. I cannot see the package in dba_objects.

Comment: I've added some more info in my message; have a look, please.

Comment: No rows selected. I don't know why the package doesn't exist.

Comment: Which 11g version do you use? I've just checked - it exists even in my 11gXE.

Comment: Oracle version is 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: The same version as mine ... huh, that's strange. I'm afraid I don't have any other ideas, sorry. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist. Consider asking the same question on SE for DBA, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: @Rene This seems to be the case. Thank you.

Comment: @Rene This seems to be the case. Thank you.